# Dynamic binding of list items in a simple To-Do List using RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, dynamic, android-recyclerview

I am trying to write a simple to-do list that will display added items using RecyclerView list. My application starts properly, but it does not add anything to the RecyclerView object that is responsible for displaying the items.

My guess is that it requires some kind of dynamic or asynchronous binding that will ensure on-the-fly addition to the list, but I am stuck at implementing it.
I tried to add custom `add` and `remove` methods to my own adapter, but still, it does not load dynamically.

Here's my code:

RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
package com.example.kandydatpl;, adapter for list items

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewAdapter";
    private ArrayList<String> listItemTexts = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<String> listItemTexts, Context context) {
        this.listItemTexts = listItemTexts;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void add(String content){
        listItemTexts.add(content);
    }

    public void remove(int position){

        listItemTexts.remove(position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_listitem, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called");

        viewHolder.listItem.setText(listItemTexts.get(i));
        viewHolder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: onClick: clicked on: " + listItemTexts.get(i));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItemTexts.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView listItem;
        CheckBox listItemCheckbox;
        RelativeLayout parentLayout;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            listItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemText);
            listItemCheckbox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);
            parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
        }
    }
}
```

TaskListActivity.java, activity on which the list is implemented

```
package com.example.kandydatpl;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TaskListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

      private EditText itemET;
      private Button btn;
//    private ListView itemsList;
//    private ArrayList<String> items;
//    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    private ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_list);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.taskList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mNames, this);

        itemET = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
//        itemsList = findViewById(R.id.list);
//
         mNames = FileHelper.readData(this);
//
//        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
//        itemsList.setAdapter(adapter);
//
          btn.setOnClickListener(this);
//        itemsList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.addBtn:
                String itemEntered = itemET.getText().toString();
                adapter.add(itemEntered);
                itemET.setText("");
                FileHelper.writeData(mNames, this);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Item Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        mNames.remove(position);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

activity_task_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/taskList"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

layout_listitem.xml, the layout for item to be displayed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/parent_layout">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/itemCheckBox"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Placeholder"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/itemCheckBox"
        android:id="@+id/itemText"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have debugged this code and it luckily the 'Add' button responds and the string entered by user is added to adapter ArrayList, but it seems that it is not retrieved from it on the activity screen.

Answer (score 1):

Short and naive solution (will make the app slow if the list is big) :
in your `add()` and `remove()` methods in the `RecyclerView.Adapter`, call this function in the end: [`notifyDataSetChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())

Longer and more elegant solution: use [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil)

And why are you seeing what you are seeing?
It's because only the `Adapter` is seeing the changes that you are implementing and not the `RecyclerView` itself. In order for the `RecyclerView` to know that the adapter state (i.e. the data) has been updated, we use `notifyDataSetChanged` or `DiffUtil` callback.